# Format in Excel 2007 to show Currency symbol and no decimal point or following zero, unless .50

Tags: microsoft-excel, format

I have an invoice, with a list of items and their charge.

Most are whole pounds, but there are 4 with a value of £2.50.  If the quantity is an odd number, the calculated result needs to display as £7.50 for example, but with an even number I want to see the result as £10 with no zeroes and no decimal point.

I accept that the column of results might not align neatly, it is more important in this case to not be cluttered with excess 00s and....s

So, this is how I want the results to display

£2.50

£10

£150

£7.50

and so on

I have tried various formats, and conditional formatting, but not getting what I need.

General format does what I want, but I need £ symbol too.   Happy to have an intermediary (hidden) column if the solution is a formula not a format.

Would love to hear of any suggestions, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This has been addressed over on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50009968/4475014). I have copied the accepted answer below. You should be able to modify it to add a currency symbol to the conditional formatting.

---

If acceptable, you may use the formula not in the sheet but as a condition for **Conditional Formatting**.

When your data is at `A1:A4` as the sample on screenshot, we should create 2 Formatting Rules:

1. Formula is: `=MOD($A1,1) = 0` Applies to: `=$A$1:$A$4` Format the number as no decimals from the format of this rule.
2. Formula is: `=MOD($A1,1) <> 0` Applies to `=$A$1:$A$4` & Format the number to show 2 decimals.

Actually the 2nd condition is optional. You may format the whole column with 2 decimals and conditional format with the first rule so only the integers will have no decimals.

Please see my sample screenshot:

[image]